# A problem occurred while writing the code to switch frames by menuBar in tikinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with the code I wrote to switch frame by menuBar at tikinter.

```py
from tkinter import *

class myApp(Tk):
    def switchFrame(self, classParam):
        if self.nowFrame: # here error occurr
            self.nowFrame.destory() # here error occurr
        self.nowFrame = classParam
        self.nowFrame.pack()

    def __init__(self, root):
        myMenu=Menu(root)
        menu1=Menu(myMenu)
        menu1.add_command(label="before", command=lambda:self.switchFrame(frameClass_1()))
        menu1.add_command(label="next", command=lambda:self.switchFrame(frameClass_2()))
        myMenu.add_cascade(label="switch", menu=menu1)
        root.config(menu=myMenu)
        root.mainloop()

class frameClass_1(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        Label(self, text="frame1").pack()

class frameClass_2(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        Label(self, text="frame2").pack()

root = Tk()
myApp(root)
```

Running that code, I get this error.

> error: [Previous line repeated 989 more times] RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: Please do not use `*` imports for tkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `self.nowFrame` inside `__init__()` and you should not inherit `myApp` from `Tk` as instance of `Tk` is passed as an argument already:

```py
class myApp:
    ...

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.nowFrame = None
        ...
```

Also there is typo error: `self.nowFrame.destory()` should be `self.nowFrame.destroy()` instead.